# Copy data between Django-Models (from View to table)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a "view" where ingredients from Larder are listed, I want to choose ingredients and specify how much of it I ate and save it in the Ingredients_eaten model, but to do this, I need to pass few data from Larder (Ingredient name, quantity, unit).  How can I do it? In View.py I know how to save data from the form (two fields), but I miss those three fields from Larder, and I don’t know to do it.

I have three models

Ingredients_bought – where the user specifies what kind of ingredient he/she buy, e.g. Milk, Eggs

Larder – this is a MySQL view which group data from ingredients_bought by name and unit (e.g., If I buy milk twice, I will see one line with quantity two)

Ingredient_eaten – in this model, I want to store information about what I ate. And here I have a problem.

View:

```
def larder_detail_view(request):

    obj = Larder.objects.all()
    form = EatForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EatForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            a = form.save(commit=False)
            a.user = request.user
            a.save()
            quantity = form.cleaned_data.get('quantity')
            unit = form.cleaned_data.get('unit')
            messages.success(request, f'Składnik  w ilości {quantity} {unit} został dodany do bazy')
            return redirect('food-larder')

    return render(request, 'food/larder.html', {'obj': obj, 'form': form})
```

Form:

```
class EatForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredients_eaten
        fields = ('quantity', 'unit')
```

Larder template:

```
{% extends "food/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
        <h1>Larder</h1>
            <table id="bootstrapdatatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                        <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" /></th>
                        <th>Ingredient name</th>
                        <th>quantity</th>
                        <th>unit</th>
                        <th>Quantity eaten</th>
                        <th>unit eaten</th>
                        <th>Sumbmit</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for ob in obj %}
                            {% if request.user == ob.user%}
                            <tr>
                                <form action ="" method="POST">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <td><input type ="checkbox" class="checkthis" /></td>
                                    <td>{{ ob.ingredient_name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ ob.quantity }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ ob.unit }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ form.quantity }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ form.unit }}</td>
                                    <td><input type="submit"></td>
                                </form>
                            </tr>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </div>
            </table>
{% endblock content%}
```

Models:

```
class Ingredients_bought(models.Model):
    ingredient_name = models.ForeignKey(Ingredients_list, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    unit = models.ForeignKey(UnitList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_time_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ingredient_name



class Ingredients_eaten(models.Model):
    ingredient_eaten = models.ForeignKey(Ingredients_bought, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient_name = models.ForeignKey(Ingredients_list, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    unit = models.ForeignKey(UnitList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_time_eaten = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ingredient_name


class Larder(models.Model):
    ingredient_name = models.ForeignKey(Ingredients_list, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(UnitList, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'food_larder'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPBLm.png)

Comment: here you want to add multiple data in single model then you require multiple forms. create forms using for loop and give initial value of ingredient_eaten, ingredient_name, user and date_time_eaten. and put these field in hidden.  and in forms.py select all fields. when user post form using single button all forms will be send to you. save it.

Comment: or you can do it without forms.py use ajax for it. iterate all <tr> and save data of each field by self.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do it but It's not going to be easy since I'm a very noob in Django :( I will let you know when I'm done :)